# How to know if a product ASIN has variations?

Tags: amazon-product-api

Whats the easiest way know if a product ASIN has variations ?
The itemsearch operation doesn't return any info in variations response group, I have tried all combinations.
The itemlookup operation won't return any info in variations response group unless its a parent ASIN.

Comment: Could you clarify your question? Are you looking for items that are similar? For instance, are you looking for a book that is published in both hardback and paperback? Perhaps you could share the ASIN that you are using for your tests.

Comment: no similar products is different. Variations mean for example a shirt with sizes medium, large etc are variations of each other. Read through http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01/DG/RG_Variations.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

variations are not returned with searchindex=All

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=83523